# Dynamically update total through dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a bit of a dilemma, i am trying to make it so that when a user selects an option from a dropdown box it dynamically updates a total on the same page, without any reloading.

In other words i have 5 different options in a dropdown box (1,2,3,4,5) and if the user selects 1 it needs to put it through a simple equation, and then output it in a "total" box on the right, the problem i want to do this dynamically with no reloading, can anyone give me any advice or tips on what i should be using and any tutorials that might help (code etc...)

Thanks

Comment: Don't ask for code. Nobody will write it without payment. As an advice I can say: Take a look at Ajax.

Comment: could you please post your html code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be accomplished with Javascript. I can recommend using jQuery as a Javascript Framework http://jquery.com/

With that it is really easy to do what you want:

```
$("select").change(function(){
     var currentValue = parseInt($(this).find("option:selected").val());
     //do whatever calculation e.g
     result = currentValue * 2 + 1;
     //output result somewhere on the page e.g.
     $("#output").html(result);
})
```

Comment: Brilliant, i just tested this now and it works, the only other thing i just thought of is, say i had two different dropdowns, that both needed to be plugged into the same equation, how might i do that?

Comment: Give both selects the same class name e.g. `class="calculate"` and then change the jQuery selector in line 1 from `$("select")` to `$(".calculate")`. _Explanation_: When using a class as a selector the change function will be called whenever an element with that class will be changed. Since you are using use the same equation in both selects this is the way to go. If you had different equations then you would need to write different functions.

Answer (score 0):

// This is the jquery you have to use in your page with ddl

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FloorId").change(function () {
            var ddlValue = $(this).val();

                $.getJSON('calculate.php', { "Id": ddlValue }, function (obj) {
                    $("total").text(obj.value);
                });
        });
    });
```

Return total in calculate page

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to store it in a database a simple use of [jquery](http://jquery.com) on client side can do it.
on the select change you retrieve the total from a input with "readonly" set and then add the current number the user have choose. remember to reset the select or an user can't add two time the same number:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#add').change(function(){
     var  total = parseInt($('input#total').val())+parseInt($(this).val());
     $('input#total').val(total);
        $('select#add option[value=""]').attr('selected', true);
    });
});
```

see this http://jsfiddle.net/3TMK8/ for a working example with html